# Got an srand error and would like to know if there are other ways to improve this code

Tags: c

Basically this is a program to play with dice but i have a problem with srand. it gives an error stating "implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'"
whys that ?

Also i would like to know if there are any other ways to improve this code? currently i only know stdio.h i know there are some out there like iostream or something like that. is there a possible way to explain those to me also.

Here is the code. 
i know crt secure no warning is to ignore some errors but i would still like to know why it the error pops up ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
 #define MAX_CHIPS 400 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   

void display_details(void); 
int throws_die(void); 
int main() so on
{
    int die1, die2, throw_sum; 
    int PointToMake; 


    int Games_Played = 0; 
    int Games_Won = 0;  
    int Games_Lost = 0; 


    int CurrentChips = MAX_CHIPS; 
        int BetChips;

    char PlayerName[30];   
    char PlayAgain; 


    display_details(); 

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Would you like to play Test your luck [y|n]?\n"); 
    scanf(" %c", &PlayAgain);
    while ((PlayAgain == 'y') && (CurrentChips > 0))
    {
        if (Games_Played == 0)//shows how many games played which is obviously 0
        {
            printf("A new chellenger! What is your name?\n");
            scanf(" %s", &PlayerName);           
            printf("Hi %s!\n", PlayerName);     
        }

        Games_Played = Games_Played + 1;//each new game it will increase by 1

        printf("Number of chips: %d\n", CurrentChips);
        printf("Place your bet:\n "); 
        scanf("%d", &BetChips); 


        while ((BetChips < 0) || (BetChips > CurrentChips))  
        {
            printf("uuh ....You can only bet the chips you have.. (0-%d)!\n", CurrentChips);
            printf("Place your bet: \n");
            scanf("%d", &BetChips);
        }


        die1 = throws_die();
        die2 = throws_die();
        throw_sum = die1 + die2;
        printf("You Got: %d + %d = %d\n", die1, die2, throw_sum);


        if ((throw_sum == 7) || (throw_sum == 12))
        {
            //+1 to games won
            Games_Won = Games_Won + 1;
            //adding to bet balance
            CurrentChips = CurrentChips + BetChips;
            printf("XXXXX  Winner! d(^_^)  XXXXX\n");
        }

        else if ((throw_sum == 2) || (throw_sum == 3) || (throw_sum == 10))
        {

            Games_Lost = Games_Lost + 1;

            CurrentChips = CurrentChips - BetChips;
            printf("XXXXX  Loser! :( XXXXX\n");
        }

        else
        {

            PointToMake = throw_sum;
            printf("Points to make is: %d\n", PointToMake);


            die1 = throws_die();
            die2 = throws_die();
            throw_sum = die1 + die2;
            printf("    |--->> Spinned: %d + %d = %d\n", die1, die2, throw_sum);


            while (throw_sum != PointToMake && throw_sum != 7)
            {
                die1 = throws_die();
                die2 = throws_die();
                throw_sum = die1 + die2;
                printf("    |--->> Spinned: %d + %d = %d\n", die1, die2, throw_sum);
            }


            if (throw_sum == PointToMake)
            {
                printf("XXXXX  Winner! (x2 the bet) XXXXX\n");
                //x2 added to balance
                CurrentChips = CurrentChips + 2 * BetChips;
                Games_Won = Games_Won + 1;
            }
            else
            {

                Games_Lost = Games_Lost + 1;
                CurrentChips = CurrentChips - BetChips;
                printf("XXXXX  Loser!:(  XXXXX\n");
            }
        }


        if (CurrentChips > 0)
        {
            printf("You now have %d chips.\n", CurrentChips);
            printf("============================\n\n");
            printf("Play Again %s [y|n]? ", PlayerName);   
            scanf(" %c", &PlayAgain);   
            printf("============================\n");
        }
        else  
        {
            printf("you're out of chips.\n");
            printf("XXXXX  GG TRY AGAIN NEXT TIME  XXXXX\n");
        }
    }


    if (Games_Played == 0)
    {
        printf("Oh well.... better luck next time!\n");
    }

    else if (Games_Played == 1)
    {
        printf("%s played %d game and is cashing out with %d chips!\n", PlayerName, Games_Played, CurrentChips);
        printf("   |---> Games won: %d\n", Games_Won);
        printf("   |---> Games lost: %d\n", Games_Lost);
        printf("Thanks for playing, come again to test that luck of yours %s.\n", PlayerName);
    }

    else
    {

        printf("%s played %d games and is cashing out with %d chips!\n", PlayerName, Games_Played, CurrentChips);
        printf("   |---> Games won: %d\n", Games_Won);
        printf("   |---> Games lost: %d\n", Games_Lost);
        printf("\nThanks for playing, come again to test that luck of yours %s!\n", PlayerName);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display_details(void)  
{
    printf("File     :.... assignment.c\n");
    printf("Author   :.... \n");
    printf("Stud ID  :.... \n");
    printf("Email ID :.... \n");
    printf("This is my own work as defined by the \n");
    printf("University's Academic Misconduct Policy.\n");
}

int throws_die(void)
{
    return 1 + rand() % 6;
```

Comment: `int main() so on` ??

Comment: I don't see anything C++ about this code. It looks more like C. And there's a separate site for [CodeReviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: the error you mention is pretty clear, you are trying attempting a narrowing conversion. but in this case you don't really care because it is just the seed for random value so just cast

Answer (score 1):

`srand` is defined more or less like this:

```
void srand(unsigned int seed);
```

`time` is defined more or less like this:

```
__int64 time(__int64 *t);
```

Thus you pass an `__int64` (64 bits) into an `unsigned int` (32 bits) parameter, which is not possible without potential trunctation. That's what the warning message is telling you.

Comment: So how should i modify this? sorry for the inconvenience, im still pretty new to all this.

Comment: @PlatoTsoi You can use `srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));`. This will tell the compiler that the cast is intended and the warning will go away.